# Cant get a SVG path to fit into SVG Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've been trying to get an SVG path to appear in the middle of my SVG rect that fills the entire svg element. So far I've tried the following things, to no avail

1. Placing path element in a `<g>` tag, and transforming the group based on values that I've gotten from `elementgetBBox()`. I would use those values, and the values of the entire SVG box to try to get the right number to scale the element down, but it still dosen't fit, nor is centered
2. Done the same thing as #1, but with a nested `<svg>` tag instead of a `<g>` tag.
3. Tried to transform the element itself.

The main problems that I am having are:

- I cant seem to find a way to dynamically fit the path element onto the square
- The path element seems to hang to the right for some reason. I would like to get it flush with the top and left sides

I have a [jsfiddle of the svg that I'm trying to work with](http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/), if that helps.

Comment: It's easy enough to fix it to center the path in the SVG by enlarging the SVG canvas -- set height and width properties to 600 and it works? http://jsfiddle.net/remus/epTp9/1/  But then getting into dynamic land, you're going to have to use some sort of variable in the `path` calculations if you want it to size accordingly.

Comment: @r3mus If I did that, then the image would appear HUGE

Answer (score 2):

here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/3/

here's the changed code for the path.

```
<g transform="scale(0.4)">
<path id="star-2-outline" d="M256,128.858l42.98,88.667l97.61,13.478l-71.047,68.278l17.346,96.996L256,349.809l-86.89,46.469l17.346-96.996l-71.047-68.278l97.61-13.478L256,128.858z M256,60.082l-62.978,129.92L49.999,209.75L154.1,309.793l-25.415,142.125L256,383.828l127.315,68.09L357.9,309.793L462.001,209.75l-143.023-19.748L256,60.082z" class="flag-icon" ></path>

  </g>
```

Comment: It fits, but isn't aligned whatsoever within the rect

Answer (score 2):

For method #2, if it's not obvious what the bounds of the path are (you are using relative path commands, so yours isn't), just experiment with the viewBox until you find the right bounds.  For your star it turns out to be (50,55 - 460,455).

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 350 200' height='200' width='350' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="350" height="200" x="0" y="0" fill="#126d62"></rect>

    <svg  width="350" height="200" x="0" y="0" viewBox="50 55 410 400">
       <path id="star-2-outline" d="M256,128.858l42.98,88.667l97.61,13.478l-71.047,68.278l17.346,96.996L256,349.809l-86.89,46.469l17.346-96.996l-71.047-68.278l97.61-13.478L256,128.858z M256,60.082l-62.978,129.92L49.999,209.75L154.1,309.793l-25.415,142.125L256,383.828l127.315,68.09L357.9,309.793L462.001,209.75l-143.023-19.748L256,60.082z" class="flag-icon" ></path>
      </svg>

</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/4/

And for method #3 it's just a matter of fuinding the right scale and then translating it to the right place.

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 350 200' height='200' width='350' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="350" height="200" x="0" y="0" fill="#126d62"></rect>

    <path id="star-2-outline" d="M256,128.858l42.98,88.667l97.61,13.478l-71.047,68.278l17.346,96.996L256,349.809l-86.89,46.469l17.346-96.996l-71.047-68.278l97.61-13.478L256,128.858z M256,60.082l-62.978,129.92L49.999,209.75L154.1,309.793l-25.415,142.125L256,383.828l127.315,68.09L357.9,309.793L462.001,209.75l-143.023-19.748L256,60.082z" class="flag-icon"
          transform="scale(0.5) translate(90 -55) "></path>

</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/5/

Comment: This works, but it's not centered very well. With the application that I'm making, sometimes the background images will be split in half, and the image looks off when that's the case

[Here's a fiddle of what it looks like with 2 colors](http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/7/)

Comment: That just means my transform was a bit off.  I pretty much did it by eye.  Change it to `translate(95 -55)` and it is better.  See http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/9/`.  The first of the two methods I list is probably the better overall solution.  Once you have found the correct viewBox, you can easily re-use the star in multiple places and have it centre itself automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the rect you want to fit an id of "rect" then this will fit the star into the rectangle:

```
var rectBBox = rect.getBBox();
var path = document.getElementById("star-2-outline");
var pathBBox = path.getBBox();

var scaleX = rectBBox.width / pathBBox.width;
var scaleY = rectBBox.height / pathBBox.height;
var translateX = rectBBox.x - pathBBox.x;
var translateY = rectBBox.y - pathBBox.y;

path.setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + scaleX + ", " + scaleY + ") translate(" + translateX + ", " + translateY + ")");
```

Comment: This isn't seem to be working [here is a fiddle with the updates you suggested](http://jsfiddle.net/epTp9/8/). When I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: That's because run is never called. Check the browser error log and you'll see it's your jsfiddle that's at fault: Here's the same code working: http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/epTp9/11/

Comment: Using the above, is it possible to preserve the aspect ratio of the path?